# Rails: Controllers and models seems to be cached in dev

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I am using Rails 3.1 and have been developing for one and a half year. This morning I must have done something, it seems now that a lot of my files seems to be cached. This includes view-files, controllers and models.

I can make changes in models, controllers etc and it will not make any effect on my app (running on localhost:3000). I have tried to switch ports (to localhost:3005 for example) but it didn't work.

I have not altered any config-files or made any large changes on my computer (Mac, Lion) but obviously I must have done something.

- I am working in development mode
- I am using TextMate on Mac
- The public folder is empty, except for 404-pages etc
- I have deleted the /caches/assets-folder
- I have deleted the cache on my browser

Restarting the server makes it work, always! Sometimes (very rarely though) changes take effect without restart.

This is my development.rb:

```
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Log error messages when you accidentally call methods on nil.
  config.whiny_nils = true

  # Show full error reports and disable caching
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Only use best-standards-support built into browsers
  config.action_dispatch.best_standards_support = :builtin

  # Raise exception on mass assignment protection for Active Record models
  config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict

  # Log the query plan for queries taking more than this (works
  # with SQLite, MySQL, and PostgreSQL)
  config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = 0.5

  # Do not compress assets
  config.assets.compress = false

  # Expands the lines which load the assets
  config.assets.debug = true
```

What could have happened and how do I solve or troubleshoot it?

Comment: Setting "config.cache_classes = true" and then back to false seem to have temporarily solved the problem... could be a clue?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem, we have exactly the same thing happening, it seems to be computer specific. On my computer it works on my colleagues computer it constantly caches classes.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably not looking at what you think you are looking at. Most common reason: you work on a copy of the project instead of the folder you are viewing when running the app.

Or you messed up your development.rb ( config.cache_classes = false ).

Tips for caching: this page has all caching techniques. Look at the one about page cache (where it does not even run through the Ruby stack).

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html

Other tip: copy the whole project to a new folder, so any folder magic by the OS does not interfere.

Does the development log not reveal any hints about what is happening? Especially if you put som illegal code in one of your major model (that really ought to crash it)...

Comment: No, that can't be it because most of the views (i.e. application.html.erb) works fine...

Comment: Oh, and config.cache_classes is supposed to be set to false, right? (it is for me, and I haven't changed it).

Comment: If the second is not true (your assumption is right), the first must be true. You are not editing the files that are used generate the webpages. Are you editing from a recent list, and starting from the command-line? Open the file without using the recent list and double check your path...

Comment: Thanks, I am 100% sure I am working on the right files. It seems now, after some trouble shooting, that it always works if I restart the application as well as almost always does NOT work if I do NOT restart (with some exceptions). It really seems I missed the cache_classes but I haven't...

Comment: Forgot to answer: No, it runs smoothly. Illegal code doesn't crash it until I restart the server again...

Comment: Then a last ditch effort :) Maybe you start production as default when not specifying the rails_env? Put some illegal code in in both development.rb and production.rb and look where it's complaining after restart...

Comment: I know this is old, but did you ever find a solution to this? I'm actually running into something similar. All the right settings in config (even tested to make sure the right config and settings are being loaded in the env). I make a change in a controller and nothing happens. If I reload the server it takes the change. I can't find anything else to tweak.

Answer (score 2):

I already had the same problem.

After adding following line in my development.rb file my issue has been resolved:

```
config.reload_classes_only_on_change = false
```

I don't understand why this issue with cache is coming. Everything was working great during 2 weeks than I got this issue.

I'm using Textmate, maybe...